# How similar is EBML to XML?

Tags: xml, parsing, matroska

So, recently, I went ahead and tried to mess around with the EBML format used by Matroska. I set a goal for me to parse the subtitles in a MKV sequentially from the binary stream.

I know the cluster, block and track ids to use and am able to get the specific subtitle track id without much issue.

The problem starts when trying to parse the rest of the file. I know subtitles are scattered around the file within blocks. The blocks are nested inside a blockgroup, which again are inside a cluster. The cluster has a general timestamp and the blocks contain offsets of that timestamp.

The problem is... I can't seem to find subtitles consistently.

Currently I am doing the simplest thing there is (which is definitely not optimal and absolutely not accurate) where I parse each cluster, each blockgroup and then each block and check if the block contains the track id. Then I convert all the binary data within that block to a string (yep). What i then would expect is that somewhere in the garbage is the actual subtitle presented as it's binary UTF-8 encoded within that block.

Now as I said, I split the binary stream using the cluster id, blockgroup id and block id. But my first "thought" was, how on earth does one detect the end of a cluster, or the end of a blockgroup, or the end of a block?

So then I started reading more about EBML (I went in fully unprepared with just the table of EBML ID's from matroska's site). I found out that EBML is supposed to be similar to XML in the way it stores data by defining tags and whatnot. I was wondering, if it's similar to XML, whereas XML uses  `<tag></tag>` format to represent the beginning and the ending of a field, does EBML do the same? What defines the end of a cluster or any other field within EBML? Is the second occurrence of an cluster ID possibly the END of that cluster? And does the next cluster start at the following cluster ID and everything in between is possibly something else? Or am I thinking to hard right now?

I might have missed something in the documentation, but I just can't seem to find a definitive answer. I will however test this myself, but if this doesn't work, I hope to find an answer that can put me in the right direction here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

EBML is not actually similar to XML. XML just happened to be popular at the time when Matroska was created, so the lead author found the XML analogy useful, and as part of the official documentation it stuck.

Elements in EBML consist of id-length-content encoding, where numeric values have variable length (1-8 bytes, determined by how many leading zero bits there are in the first byte). There are no end tags, and no "attributes" as in XML.

The format is really difficult to parse yourself, so you'd better use existing EBML parsers, or even MKV tools. Ports are available for all popular programming languages from C to Node.js and Python.

Comment: Recommend any specific/official parsers?

Comment: AFAIK the only implementation is libebml, for which there are bindings to all popular programming languages.